# Does Google API OAuth require login with web page?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-api-java-client, youtube-data-api

I need to fetch YouTube video comments with YouTube API, but it seems that must login in web page at first time. Is there any way to access YouTube video comment API without webpage login? I don't like to click the login button or any thing in web page manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to be authenticated with OAuth to return a thread of comments from a video.  You just need an API key.  Hit the [`commentThreads/list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) endpoint with the following parameters:

`part` -> `id,snippet`

`videoId` -> `jCHE0Tjw6MA` (or the video ID you want to return the comments for)

```
HTTP GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=id%2Csnippet&videoId=jCHE0Tjw6MA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```